# Can's send email from gmail.com by Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

In my spring boot app:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EmailService {

@Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;


    public void sendEmail(String emailTo, NotifyActionEnum actionEnum, String orderId)
            throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException {
        String subject = "Order with number " + orderId + " was success";           
        SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
        msg.setTo(emailTo);
        msg.setSubject("Order notification: " + appName + " ver." + appVersion);
        msg.setText(subject);
        javaMailSender.send(msg);
    }
```

In appplication.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8091
  servlet:
    contextPath: /api/v1

spring:
  application:
    name: My app name
  http:
    converters:
      preferred-json-mapper: gson
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: some_my_account@gmail.com
    password: some_my_account_pass
    tls: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
      auth: true
      starttls.enable: true
      ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

But when try to send mail by my app I get error:

```
2020-03-08 18:18:17.753  INFO 16092 --- [nio-8091-exec-1] r.o.s.e.controllers.NotifyController     : notifyByEmail: email = a_subscriber@mail.ru, notifyActionEnum = ORDER_DELETE, orderId = 10
2020-03-08 18:18:23.189 ERROR 16092 --- [nio-8091-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l3sm57702489wrq.62 - gsmtp
] with root cause

javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l3sm57702489wrq.62 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:947) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:762) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:437) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:323) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:312) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.myprojectservice.EmailService.sendEmail(EmailService.java:47) ~[main/:na]
    at com.myprojectcontrollers.NotifyController.notifyByEmail(NotifyController.java:33) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
```

P.S. But if I open browser on gmail.com I success login by my credentials to gmail.com.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the link? Chances are Gmail is blocking you as they consider the mail client insecure, there are steps in there to get around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an [App password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) for Google to allow your application to send e-mails from your account.

Also, please turn on [less secure app access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) in your account.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use your personal password to log in with your Spring Boot application. Consider creating an application password.

There is a [good tutorial](https://mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) on this from Mkyong